# VSCode, C++ and CMake - One launch configuration per target

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I use Visual Studio Code and the [CMake extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) to work on a big project. The project consists of some libraries and executables which all are available as separate cmake build targets.

I configured VSCode / *tasks.json* to build the selected target with its default build.task:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "CMake build",
      "type": "cmake",
      "command": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the selected *build target* is build whenever I hit `<Ctrl-Shift-b>`.

Then I created a launch configuration by creating a *launch.json* file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
      "args": ["--serialPort","/dev/ttyS0"],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${command:cmake.launchTargetDirectory}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, whenever I hit `F5` the gdb debugger is started with the selected *launch target*.

This works fine except, that only *one* of the launch targets needs the `"args": ["--serialPort","/dev/ttyS0"]` that I provided. Some of the others refuse to start with this args given.

So, is there a way to have separate args for separate targets in VSCode with cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#fileaskey) v1.17.0

If you use the command `extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey` you can use the command variable `${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}` to get the path that is used for matching keys (file path parts) to command line arguments.

The chosen default value (`-v0`) is a command option that is accepted by the other programs but does not do a major thing. `-v` is often chosen to select a debug log level.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
      "args": ["${input:arg1}", "${input:arg2}"],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${command:cmake.launchTargetDirectory}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "arg1",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        "@useCommand": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
        "@default": "-v0",
        "proj1": "--serialPort"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "arg2",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        "@useCommand": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
        "@default": "-v0",
        "proj1": "/dev/ttyS0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edit**

In version 1.18.1 I have added debug logs to the `fileAsKey` command.

1. Add the following line to the `args` property:

   ```
   "@debug": true
   ```
2. Open the Developer tools of VSC: **Help** > **Toggle Developer Tools**
3. Clear the console
4. Launch the debug session with <kbd>F5</kbd>

In the console you find a lot of text and you should find the following messages if `fileAsKey` executes without error:

```
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: debug logs enabled
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: use command variable: ${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: execute command: cmake.launchTargetPath
[Extension Host] [CMakeTools] [debug] [extension] [6927] cmake.launchTargetPath started
[Extension Host] [CMakeTools] [debug] [cache] Reading CMake cache file C:/Projects/cmakeQuickStart/build/CMakeCache.txt
.....
[Extension Host] [CMakeTools] [debug] [extension] [6927] cmake.launchTargetPath finished (returned "C:\\Projects\\cmakeQuickStart\\build\\helloAll.exe")
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: execute command result: C:\Projects\cmakeQuickStart\build\helloAll.exe
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: path used: C:/Projects/cmakeQuickStart/build/helloAll.exe
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: default value: -v0
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: try key: helloAll
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: before variable substitution: /dev/ttyS0
[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: after variable substitution: /dev/ttyS0
```

Comment: Many thanks for pointing a promising way to solve it! Great to discover something new to me:-) But unfortunately it doesn't run on my config. VSCode shows an error box `"Running the contributed command 'extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey' failed."`. But in *CMake/Build* log (log level = trace) it shows `extension] [1647] cmake.launchTargetPath finished (returned ".../proj1"`properly. Do you maybe have a suggestion how I can find out why it failed?

Comment: @phibel See my edit. Let me know which steps are logged.

Comment: So, I did, and strangely, there are only `[Extension Host] [CMakeTools]` items visible in log, and none of `[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey`.

Comment: are you sure you have installed the extension and restarted VSC

Comment: After restarting VSCode there are 4 related items: 1) `[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: debug logs enabled`, 2) `[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: use command variable: ${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}`, 3) `[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: execute command: cmake.launchTargetPath`, 4) `[Extension Host] commandvariable.file.fileAsKey: execute command result: _path_trimmed_/proj1`,

Comment: @phibel The next line in the code replaces the \ with / and returns this as the result of a Promise that is unpacked by an `await` statement and the result of the unpack is logged with `path used:` message. There is no error log in the console after the `execute command result:` message. Do you run this on a remote machine? Node versions differ for VSC and VSC remote.

Comment: Yes I'm running it in WSL with Debian Buster. VScode is installed on Windows side and is in WSL remote mode.

Comment: @phibel `string.replaceAll` is supported in Nodejs v15 and [VSC use Nodejs v8.7 and VSC remote uses Nodejs v7.8](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4692). I replaced that call to something node v7 understands and published version v1.18.2 of the extension

Answer (score 1):

This might not address the issue, but if you are just having trouble to select the right target to launch, then follow these instructions:
Try the command: `CMake: set debug target` and choose the one you want. To enter a command got to `Menu > View > Command Palette` or use shortcut `Shift + Ctrl + P`. Another option is to look at the bottom bar and not only change the 'build' target, but also the 'launch' target, showing to the right of the bug (debug) symbol and the triangle (run) symbol.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).